# Not a MessageBox related error that is thrown when using a MessageBox server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iis

The title is most likely confusing for most, so I'll explain it thoroughly.

This is the error I'm getting:

**Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.**

However, it's not being thrown as a result of a MsgBox being used server side.

Another wrench in the mix, this is only occuring on our current production server.  The test server, which is set up identically to the production (with the exception of the SSL Cert being different, but that won't matter), is working flawlessly.  The dev machine also works without error.

Current code being used in VB codebehind:

```
Dim DBconn As New OracleConnect 'Custom class file
Try

        DBconn.Open(Uname, Pword, SelServ)
        If DBconn Is Nothing Then
            errorLabel.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password."
            Exit Sub
        Else
            groups = DBconn.GetUserRole()

            'Create the ticket, and add the groups.
            Dim isCookiePersistent As Boolean = chkPersist.Checked
            Dim authTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, _
                 txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups)

            'Encrypt the ticket.
            Dim encryptedTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket)

            'Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)

            If (isCookiePersistent = True) Then
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration
            End If
            'Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie)

            'set session variables
            Session("UID") = txtUsername.Text
            Session("PWD") = txtPassword.Text
            Session("selServ") = StrServer.SelectedValue

            SetupTableNames()

            'MsgBox(groups, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "HRIS User Role")
            Session("gsRole") = groups

            'You can redirect now.
            'Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, False))
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/_Search.aspx")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLabel.Text = "Error authenticating. " & ex.Message
    End Try
```

Code from OracleConnect class:

```
Public Sub Open(ByVal Uname As String, ByVal Pword As String, ByVal SelServ As String)

    OraDb = "Data Source=" + SelServ +
            ";Persist Security Info=True" +
            ";User Id=" + Uname +
            ";Password=" + Pword

    conn = New OracleConnection(OraDb)
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As OracleException
        Select Case ex.Number
            Case 1
                MesgBox("Error attempting to insert duplicate data.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "HRIS")

            Case 12545
                MesgBox("The database is unavailable.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "HRIS")

            Case Else
                MesgBox("Database error: " + ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "HRIS")
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        MesgBox(ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, "HRIS")

    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm aware of the MesgBox's in the class file but those are referencing a Sub the uses Javascript that works within the program which has been tested and works as it should.

So my questions are:

Is there something that would trigger this response server side in IIS 7.0 that I haven't found yet?

If it's not viable in IIS, then are there any alternatives that I should look into?

**EDIT: The solution to this problem didn't lie within the ASP or VB code but rather with the Oracle set up on the server.  For anyone that has a similar problem in the future, I advise looking into the TNS_ADMIN environment/system variables and the TNSNAMES.ORA file and make sure they are correct.  If you make any of these changes, make sure to restart the server.  My steps involved verifying the TNSNAMES.ORA file was correct, the TNS_ADMIN environment variable was set, then in a cmd prompt using "set tns_admin={filepath}", after all that then restart the server and the site was working perfectly.**

Comment: Can we see what MesgBox does?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I would deliberately try to open a msgbox() on your test server to make sure IIS is not set for interactive mode. If you get this same error then move on. Otherwise, your test server is not set up identical to your production server. I can't think of any other reason why this would occur on one and not the other. Also, naming your class 'MesgBox' is just asking for trouble. I would give it something a little more unique.

Comment: It ended up being an error in my Oracle TNSNAMES.ORA file and associated settings with the TNS_ADMIN system variable.  Both of which I was told were set up by my server admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem didn't lie within the ASP or VB code but rather with the Oracle set up on the server. For anyone that has a similar problem in the future, I advise looking into the TNS_ADMIN environment/system variables and the TNSNAMES.ORA file and make sure they are correct. If you make any of these changes, make sure to restart the server. My steps involved verifying the TNSNAMES.ORA file was correct, the TNS_ADMIN environment variable was set, then in a cmd prompt using "set tns_admin={filepath}", after all that then restart the server and the site was working perfectly.